# Having proplem with Python 3.5 after installing Python 3.7

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, python-3.5, python-3.7

I had Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 and then I installed Python 3.7 and made it the default Python.

Now most of the programs I run go Python 3.7 but some run on 3.5 (I don't know why).

Also, the system says that there is a problem with python 3.5 but I can't figure what it is.

Can anyone help?

Thank You

Comment: Can you please share the error and steps you did.

Comment: The error that ubuntu says it: System Problem was Detected.

Answer (score 0):

Configure PYTHON_PATH pointing proper library path or set path environment variable pointing to correct Python version.

Comment: I tried the command: sudo update-alternatives --config python and then I chose python 3.7. It works (when I write Python it opens the Python 3.7) but still sometimes the code runs on Python 3.5

Comment: Refer this Link - https://benzidwael.wordpress.com/2015/04/17/installing-different-python-versions-in-ubuntu/, 2 options mentioned. One as you mentioned in your comment and other one virtualenv.

Comment: may be check your user bash profile ( env) , I doubt it might be due to env vairble pointing to multiple version based on terminal.